# Expectation of a product envolving conditional expectation

Tags: probability

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and $\mathcal{G}\subset\mathcal{F}$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra. Assuming $X, Y \in \mathcal{L}^{2}(P)$, prove that:
>
> $$E[\,X\dot\,E[\,Y|\mathcal{G}\,]]=E[\,Y\dot\,E[\,X|\mathcal{G}\,]]$$

My initial strategy was to prove the statement for $X, Y$ being indicator functions. Having proved that, I could then use the linearity and monotonicity of the expectation to extend the statement for all non-negative $X, Y$ using the Monotone Convergence Theorem. Finally, having proved that, I could then use a positive-negative decomposition for $X, Y$ to prove it for arbitrary $X, Y$.

The problem is that I'm having trouble to prove it for $X=1_{A}, Y=1_{B}$, with $A, B \in \mathcal{F}-\mathcal{G}$, because I don't know how to deal with $E[1_{A}|\mathcal{G}]$ nor $E[1_{B}|\mathcal{G}]$.

Does this strategy work? Is there a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a quick proof: Re-express the two sides of your equality using $E[WZ] = E[ E[WZ\mid{\cal G}] ]$ with appropriate choices of $W$ and $Z$.

Answer (score 0):

$$E[X E[Y\mid \mathcal G]] = E[E[X E[Y \mid \mathcal G] \mid \mathcal G]]
= E[E[X \mid  \mathcal G] E[Y \mid \mathcal G]]$$
and similarly for the other one.

Comment: why is your first equation true?

Comment: $E[Z] = E[E[Z \mid \mathcal G]]$ where $Z = X E[Y \mid \mathcal G]$.